# Unable to resolve ../assets/image.png but i already install expo-asset on my project

Tags: react-native, png, jpeg, expo, assets

I'm trying to use Unable image in assets followed by expo preloading and Caching assets but it shows this error:

> Unable to resolve ../assets/image.png

I have already installed expo-asset on my project and my image already stays in assets as JPG and PNG but it still does nothing.

[image]

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View }  from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase'
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import  MusicApp  from './App/index'; 

function cacheImages(images) {
        return images.map(image => {
          if (typeof image === 'string') {
            return Image.prefetch(image);
          } else {
            return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
          }
        });   } export default class RegisterScreen extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = {
            header: null
        }
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
              isReady: false
            };
        }
        async _loadAssetsAsync() {
            const imageAssets = cacheImages([require('./assets/LUMO-logo.jpg')]);

            await Promise.all([...imageAssets]);
        }
        render(){
            if(!this.state.isReady){
                return(
                    <AppLoading
                            startAsync={this._loadAssetsAsync}
                            onFinish={() => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
                            onError={console.warn}
                    />
                );
            }
            return <MusicApp />;
        } } const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        },   
    });
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in which file you are, so you should double check that your image is matching the path with `require(...)`.

Be careful with `'../../some/path/img.png'` or `'../some/path/img.png'`